# Assign member to multiple member groups

Tags: members

Is it possible to assign a single user to multiple member groups / is there a module that does this?

I currently have several member groups, but they're not mutually exclusive. A La, "some dogs are black, but not all black things are dogs"

Currently I would have to setup something like the following:

- Group A only
- Group B only
- Group C only
- Group A + B
- Group A + C
- Group B + C
- Group A + B + C

Is there a more efficient route forward?

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, you just want to categorize your members. Am I right? If this is your intention, I suggest you to try [AB Member Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-member-categories). Zoo Visitor and Solspace User looks like so much power for so little needs.

Comment: Good call Robson, Thanks for this, didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the add-ons that convert members to entries can do it. [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor), [Safecracker Registration](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker-registration), [Profile Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) - I think each take variations on the approach of using categories as member groups, and then syncing your member channel entries with the member module.  And since they use categories, you can assign a user to more than one. Solspace's [User](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/user) module allows you to assign members to more than one group, but it handles it a bit differently, I believe, and adds a bunch of other member-oriented functionalities as well.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I'll take a look at some third party solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the native Members module but you can do it with Zoo Visitor.

Zoo Visitor handles your members as entries so you get the full use of custom fields and categories. The latter can be used to set up group memberships and allow you to put a single member in more than one group.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this late in this thread, I have a [multiple membership module](https://www.debeer.com/index.php/debeer/expressionengine_meet_multiple_memberships) that does exactly what is asked by Jamie.

Bear in mind this V0.9 Beta. [Suggestions for development](https://www.debeer.com/index.php/hooblong#todo) are available.